# How to find where a thread was originally started

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

Supposed I have an application that can spawn multiple threads if needed for doing tasks ... so nothing special. I use Eclipse to write and debug Java applications. A thread (lets call it "async task") is immediatly respawned after it leaves the run() method (so there is bug and I want to find the reason for this behavior).

My question, if I pause this thread "async task" using the eclipse IDE (debug perspective ..) is there way to find out where this thread was originally started (for example using the Debug view or any other)? Because I want to know who spawns this thread (without making a text search or something like this).

Is there a good way to get this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would set a breakpoint at `Thread.start()` and enable a condition

[image]

Whenever a thread named "async task" is started the condition is evaluated to true and the thread that invokes the start method is paused. Then you can see in the stacktrace from where the call came.

Comment: the problem is there are several <Thread>.start() calls, because it's a big application, this is the reason I don't want to make a text search for all start() methods.

Comment: ok, or do you mean to put this break point within the java.lang.Thread class? This could do it!

Comment: @FrecherxDachs but the breakpoint will only break if the name is equal to `async task`. Sure if there are many threads named async tasks than all will break and you must analyse all.

Comment: @FrecherxDachs Yes, that is what I mean. Put the breakpoint in the Thread class's start method.

Comment: Thank you, I know about conditional break points. "async task" was just a placeholder for this issue description.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem in production and wrote a litte java agent that logs the stack of every thread start. So the system can run and you get the info live in the log. That helps a lot, when you have many threads. https://github.com/xdev-software/thread-origin-agent

Answer (score 0):

You can't check whether new `thread` start or not by using `debuger` since `debug` will hang your entire `JVM`.

You can put some `logs` and check how `threads` works there.