# How to find the class implementing the thread from a thread dump?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump

In my thread dump I found this lines:

```
"lir" daemon prio=5 tid=7f927c7b0000 nid=0x121f40000 in Object.wait() [121f3f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7f70bedf0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
    - locked <7f70bedf0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

How can I find the class which implements or starts this `Thread` or `Runnable`?

Comment: As you can easily see in the stack trace: It's the TimeThread of java.util.Timer. I assume it's waiting for new TimerTasks to get scheduled for execution. In case you're searching for a deadlock: This thread is most probably not the reason!

Comment: Yes, I can read the stack trace ;-). But that's not really helpfull. There are 99 places where `TimerThread` is used and 64 places where `TimerThread.run()` is called :-(. What I really need is where the threads are started.

Comment: TimerThread implements the Runnable. As to what called start() - this information is lost at this point. From the call stack, these threads are probably started when you (or something) creates a Timer object

Comment: Yes, of course. In my big application this happens at dozens of places. Investigating all of theme would be very time consuming.

Comment: @BetaRide Maybe I don't understand, but TimerThread.run() is only called by the thread itself. And it is started only in the constructors of Timer.

Comment: Aftet all I think this is a dupcliate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325553/how-to-find-where-a-thread-was-originally-started . I just set the break point condition to "lir" and was able to find the guilty code easily.

Answer (score 0):

Two "semi-solutions" I can think of:

- Using the Eclipse debugger when a process is run in debug mode (there are probably equivalents in other environments), if you suspend execution, you can inspect the stack trace of any given thread and perhaps find useful information in the top level element
- Using setName() on a thread as an indication of where it was created or the name of the thread subclass